# How does password checking in bcrypt work?

Tags: python, bcrypt

So, I found the following example in `bcrypt` [docs](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/):

```
password = b"super secret password"
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
    print("It Matches!")
else:
    print("It Does not Match :(")
```

And it seems to work. But I don't understand how. Shouldn't we use salt to generate a hash for checking?

I mean, we generated salt once and didn't save it in a variable. But then we want to compare the hash and the password with the function `checkpw`, but how does it know which salt to use to generate a hash for comparison?

Comment: The salt is stored as part of the combined hash. When the password is checked the combined hash is split into the salt and password hash then the provided password with the salt is hashed and checked against the password hash

Comment: Oh, okay, got it. Thank you! If you add this comment as an answer, I will mark it as one

Comment: @IainShelvington if you do, please leave me a comment, as I wish to retract my own answer as redundant.

Comment: The answer from @LSerni is pretty good, I'll save my keyboard :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The generated "hash" also contains the salt. It is in the Modular Crypt Format, documented [here](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html) (thanks @Masklinn)

```
$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy
      |<---    salt     --->||<---- confirmation hash ---->|
```

The "2a" part gives information on the modular hash being used, "10" is the logarithmic cost parameter (i.e. the algorithm is to be iterated 2<sup>10</sup> times).

So, to verify that a password matches, you'll restart the bcrypt using the decoding of `N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye` as a salt.

Comment: Maybe link to Passlib's page on the [modular crypt format](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html) as it explains more generally how the format is generated and what information it contains?

Answer (score 5):

The salt gets saved in the hash itself. The scheme for bcrypt looks like the following:

```
$<used_algorithm>$<cost_factor>$<generated_salt><hash>$
```